# Flutter: How to get Firebase document ID and store under my model ID

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question, is it possible to have auto generated ID from Firebase stored under my model ID? so that in future I can update the data using the ID.

This is my class model:

```
  class Timeline {
  String id; // I have ID here
  String? date;
  String? time;
  String? topic;
  bool? isDone = false;

  Timeline({this.id = '', this.date, this.time, this.topic, this.isDone});

  Timeline.fromSnapshot(snapshot)
      : id = snapshot.data()['id'],
        date = snapshot.data()['date'],
        time = snapshot.data()['time'],
        topic = snapshot.data()['topic'],
        isDone = snapshot.data()['isDone'];

  factory Timeline.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Timeline(
      id: json['id'],
      date: json['date'],
      time: json['time'],
      topic: json['topic'],
      isDone: json['isDone']);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {'id': id, 'date': date, 'time': time, 'topic': topic, 'isDone': isDone};
}
```

This is my add function:

```
void addFunction() async {
final uid =
    await Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).getCurrentUID();
if (dateController.text.trim().isNotEmpty &&
    timeController.text.trim().isNotEmpty &&
    topicController.text.trim().isNotEmpty) {
  await db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('time-line').add(
      Timeline(
              id: , // I want to add the firebase auto generated ID here, is it possible?
              date: dateController.text.trim(),
              time: timeController.text.trim(),
              topic: topicController.text.trim(),
              isDone: false)
          .toJson());
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text(
    'All fields required!',
    style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'poppins', fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
  )));
}
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

}

What I want to achieve is I want to put the firebase auto generated ID in my model ID so that in future I can update other specific document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```dart
DocumentReference ref = db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('time-line').doc();

await db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('time-line').doc(ref.id).set(
      Timeline(
              id: ref.id , 
              date: dateController.text.trim(),
              time: timeController.text.trim(),
              topic: topicController.text.trim(),
              isDone: false)
          .toJson());
```